# Python: Problems getting key presses to work

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a game with 2 moving rectangles controlled by keypresses, w and s, Up and Down arrow. But I am only getting one of them to move (The one controlled by the arrows) despite that they have the same code and just different names. I have tried to figure it out but with no luck, so I really need some help getting the second one to move.(I have also tried outher ways I seen on this site like keysym but it didn’t work either)
Thanks!

The rectangles code:

```
class Block:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color, x1, y1):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(20, 10, 35, 90, fill = color)
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x1, self.y1)

        self.speed_1 = 0
        self.speed_2 = 0
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-w>', self.turn_up_1)  #Not working
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-s>', self.turn_down_1) #Not working
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Up>', self.turn_up_2) #working
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Down>', self.turn_down_2) #working

    def turn_up_1(self, evt): #Not working
        self.speed_1 = -3
    def turn_down_1(self, evt): #Not working
        self.speed_1 = 3
    def draw_1(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 0, self.speed_1) #Not working

    def turn_up_2(self, evt):  #working
        self.speed_2 = -3
    def turn_down_2(self, evt): #working
        self.speed_2 = 3
    def draw_2(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 0, self.speed_2) #working

block1 = Block(canvas, 'blue', 0, 0)
block2 = Block(canvas, 'red', 940, 540)
```

The loop:

```
while True:
    block1.draw_1() #Not working
    block2.draw_2() #Working
    time.sleep(0.0333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333)
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
```

Comment: Both of your `Block`s are binding to all four keys, but only two of them are meaningful to that object.  `block2` therefore gets all of the events, since it overwrote the bindings created by `block1`, so `block1` can never receive any keys.  Have the two keysyms be parameters to `Block`, so that each instance can bind only the keys it needs.

Comment: Thank you!! This really help. Now it is working as I wanted it to!